# Connecting to a https url from java

Tags: java, https

How do I connect to an URL using Java? I am looking to get the content from an https website.

Comment: Had you considered using the URL class?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps.
Dont forget to URLEncode your URL. To see what the header for your specific request should look like, you could for example use Firebug extension for Firefox.

```
String url=YOUR_URL;
String message=YOUR_REQUEST_HEADER

SocketFactory sslSocketFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
String response = "";
try {
 URL url = new URL(url);
 Socket socket = sslSocketFactory.createSocket(url.getHost(),     url.getPort()==-1?443:url.getPort());

PrintWriter toServer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
toServer.println(message);
toServer.flush();

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), "UTF8"));

char[] buf = new char[4096];
int bytesRead;
while((bytesRead = in.read(buf)) != -1){
 response = response + new String(buf).substring(0, bytesRead);
}

in.close();
socket.close();

} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e){
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```